# Checking for duplicates when importing to CoreData

Tags: ios, performance, core-data, restkit, nsfetchrequest

I'm importing data into a Core Data store using RestKit and need to check for duplicates.  If the item is already in the store, I'd like to update it with the latest attributes.  If it's a new item, I'd like to create it.

The import was slow so I used Instruments and saw that the longest part of importing was checking to see if the item already exists (with a fetch request)

So I'd like to know if checking to see if the item is already in the store, is it faster to:

- use countForFetchRequest to see if the item already exists, then executeFetchRequest to return the item to update or
- just executeFetchRequest to get the item to update
- or is there a better way to do this?

I thought countForFetchRequest would be faster since the entire NSManagedObject isn't returned and only execute the fetch request if I know there's going to be a NSManagedObject.

Thanks

`- (Product *)productWithId:(int)productID {`

```
    NSManagedObjectContext *context = [Model sharedInstance].managedObjectContext;
    NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"product_id == %d", productID];
    NSFetchRequest *request = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
    request.entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Product" inManagedObjectContext:context];
    request.predicate = predicate;
    request.fetchLimit = 1;

    NSError *error = nil;

    NSUInteger count = [context countForFetchRequest:request error:&error];

    if (!error && count == 1) {
        NSArray *results = [context executeFetchRequest:request error:&error];
        if (!error && [results count]) {
            return [results objectAtIndex:0];
        }
        return nil;
    }

    return nil;
```

`}`

Comment: I haven't done much performance check on it but I use  `[fetchRequest setFetchLimit:1];` and `countForFetchRequest` and I haven't really notice any performance issues. How many objects are being updated? Are you only sending objects that need to be updated? (from the web service)

Comment: Also make sure your not doing the syncing on the main thread

Comment: Multiple items come in from the API at a time and they all need to be checked for duplicates.  It's not just one at a time.

Comment: What I mean is when you send a request to the web service are you checking that the objects NEED to be updated (have they changed) a simple way to do so is to set an updateDate on each item and send that to the web service with the id, if its before the server date, the server will send that object in JSON. However this won't affect the speed of fetching from core data.

Comment: It's a flash sale site, so the in stock status of the products changes frequently.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far I know, the best way to find and/or import objects within Core Data is described in [Implementing Find-or-Create Efficiently](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/conceptual/CoreData/Articles/cdImporting.html).

The documentation describes a *find or create* pattern that it's based on sorting data: the data you download from the service and the data you grab form the store.

I really suggest you to read the link I provided. You will see a speed up on your performances.

Obviously you should do the work in background, preventing the main thread to freeze, using thread confinement or new iOS Core Data queue API.

Hope that helps.

Comment: page cannot be found. :(